# ajax/jQuery .load() function returning only text not image or background file

Tags: jquery

Whenever I'm loading a page onto a div using .load() function, it returns only the text not the background image or the any image which is in the page.

**index.html**

```
<html>
<title> web page </title>
<body>
<div id="Content" >
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
</body
</html>
```

**page.html** *(page which is going to load onto div id="Content")*

```
<html>
<title> web page </title>
<body>
<div>
<h1> WELCOME TO THIS LOADED PAGE </h1>
<img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
</body
</html>
```

**jquery.js**
`$(document).ready(function(){
$('#content').load('page.html');
});`

It finally shows only **WELCOME TO THIS LOADED PAGE** but not the image included in the **page.html**.

Thank you.

Comment: Is the image.jpg in the same folder as index.html?  Is index.html in the same folder as page.html?  Does the image some up on page.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not displaying any images on the page, theres a chance you're not pointing to the correct location where the images are stored. Are the images located in another directory?

`<img src="image.jpg" />`

may need to be something such as:

`<img src="./images/image.jpg" />`